# Did a particle hit the second stage of the Falcon Heavy in this video from the Starman stream?

Tags: spacex, engines, tesla-roadster, space-dust

The silver material surrounding the base of the Falcon Heavy second-stage engine jerks suddenly in this video from the Starman stream at 3:31:26

Is this due to a particle impact?

Answer (score 5):

I can't answer definitively, but based on my hypervelocity impact testing experience, that doesn't really look like what you'd get if a thin sheet was hit by high-speed orbital debris -- there's no light flash, no vapor cloud, and no noticeable hole afterward.  It looks more to me like something behind it moved suddenly.

Answer (score 2):

I also cannot answer definitively, but can add that the thermal radiation shielding moves several times from this camera view.

I did not watch all 4 hours of the video to see how many times it moved but I did see it happen at the following times in the video.

1:21:43

1:56:45

2:59:40

Other than something moving underneath of the shielding, my best guess would be thermal expansion and contraction... but I did not study the film enough to determine if there was a pattern of where the sunlight/shadow was impacting the shielding and if there was movement in correlation to that.